# UI for setting up availabilities

Tags: usability, interaction-design

**Background**: allow vendors to setup their availability for booking, on a mobile app. Availability goes down to hourly basis (e.g. minimum 1 hour blocks).

**Goal**: allow different types of user (part-timer/full-timer/freelancer) to setup the availability

**Common usage patterns we've known**:

- ~50% part-timers: after working hours (e.g. every weekday 7pm-midnight
  and day-time weekends)
- ~35% full timers: almost everyday with random off days
- ~15% freelancers: have no specific short-term patterns

Worth to mention, both part-timer/full-timer consist of mainly older audience who are not familiar with mobile apps

---

Solutions proposed so far:

*2 step setup process:*

- step 1: setup a weekly recurring timeframe (i.e. weekday evening +
  night)
- step 2: customise down to the hourly slot for each day (still weekly recurring basis)

[image]

*editing availability*

- editing down to specific date and time is possible

Problems:

- too complicated
- user don't know what to do

Comment: "...mainly older audience who are not familiar with mobile apps." Is that a determination from testing that group, or an assumption based on age? ...curious.

Comment: Allow me to get some nit-picky questions about the screens off my chest... Why start with blue background then change to white halfway through—and welcome message for that matter? On screen 3, what's the difference between the back pointing arrow at the top and the "Back" button? Screen 4, why change button style?

Answer (score 0):

Allow the smaller group of people who don't want to set up weekly schedules to skip directly to your customization screen—#4, by adding something like a "Let me customise..." button below the weekday selections:

[image]     [image: customise]

Also, screen #1, write "Which weekdays..." to clarify the weekly nature of the configuration.